# Cannot connect new users to pluggable database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sql-developer, oracle-18c

I'm new to Oracle DB (coming from MS SQL Server).

For a start, I downloaded a Docker container for Oracle Database 18c XE.

When I run that container, after creating a pluggable database, I don't seem to be able to connect with new users I create:

[image: Cannot connect]

As far as I can see I provided all necessary bits and bites to get these users at the ready. But what am I missing? I don't get it, even after reading dozens of doc and help pages.

Here's the output of `lsnrctl status`, run in the container:

```
> lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 25-MAY-2021 11:57:33

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                25-MAY-2021 11:11:15
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 46 min. 17 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/5854b834e19c/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=5854b834e19c)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/opt/oracle/admin/XE/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "c323f0bfe62f0aaee053030011ac1ec5" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "c323f7dc51bd0b68e053030011acc9a8" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "mobydick" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xepdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

And this is my `tnsnames.ora` file content:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))  

XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))    
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SID = PLSExtProc)
       (PRESENTATION = RO)
     )
  )



mobydick =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = mobydick)
    )
  )
```

I created the pluggable database similar to this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=CDB$ROOT;

CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE "mobydick" ADMIN USER "sa" IDENTIFIED BY "abc123" ROLES=(dba) FILE_NAME_CONVERT=('/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/dbs/mobydick/') STORAGE UNLIMITED

ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE mobydick OPEN READ WRITE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the SQL statement that SQL Developer generated:

```
CREATE USER "test" IDENTIFIED BY "abc123" ;
```

This makes the username case-sensitive, so the actual username can be used as `"test"`.

You tried to login in SQL Developer using the username `test`. This is not case-sensitive syntax, and it is automatically treated as `"TEST"`, but that user does not exist.

Use the case-sensitive syntax for username, so instead of `test`, provide `"test"` as username.

By the way, we almost never use case-sensitive usernames or object names. You could just create the user without double quotes, and your connection attempt would work:

```
CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY "abc123" ;
```

> Given that I wanted to connect using a lowercase user name by means of `sqlplus`, what would I have to enter to connect as "test", for instance? I don't seem to be able to use quotes in the `CONNECT` clause.

`"` is special character in bash shell, you need to escape it to use it in commandline arguments: `sqlplus \"test\"/abc123@mobydick`. The `connect` command handles double quotes just fine: `sqlplus /nolog` then at `SQL>` prompt,  `connect "test"/abc123@mobydick`.